# How to add new dialect to Alembic besides built-in dialects?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic, pyhive

[Alembic](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/) support 5 built-in dialects only: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/tree/master/alembic/ddl

Now I want to manages schema in Apache Hive via alembic and noticed that [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) supports SQLAlchemy interfaces so technically Alembic can support hive as a new dialect. So I've found this post [Integrate PyHive and Alembic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sqlalchemy-alembic/pyhive$20alembic%7Csort:date/sqlalchemy-alembic/t3KmE9KDzH4/KmcA4kryCwAJ) but it *seems* needs hacking `alembic/ddl/impl.py` within package `alembic`.

Is there any working way to do this? I don't mind contributing PRs to either alembic or pyHive but needs guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sqlalchemy-alembic/t3KmE9KDzH4/AK1UylnCCQAJ) in the original email list to get enough information:

> Does it mean it must introduce dependency to alembic (since it uses `alembic.ddl.impl.DefaultImpl`) in a package (.e.g, pyHive) that supports sqlalchemy interfaces?

well you have to put it in a try/except ImportError block so that if alembic isn't installed, it silently passes.

> is there any guidance to support this at alembic level in a plug-gable way? E.g., declare a HiveImpl class in `env.py` of a project uses alembic?

you could put one in your env.py also but if you are the person working on the dialect you can have this built in, see the example in sqlalchemy-redshift: https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/blob/master/sqlalchemy_redshift/dialect.py#L27